# Does AD LDS provides any callback APIs when the data within gets modified?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, adam, adlds

I am using AD LDS to store my application configuration data. I want to export the data from AD LDS to a folder everytime when the data gets modified in AD LDS.
I could not find any APIs to get callback from AD LDS when there is a modification( i have checked LDAP APIs).

Any idea how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK all of the mechanisms outlined here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677625(v=vs.85).aspx - work with AD LDS as well.